# Email não esta chegando com mail()

Tags: php

Quero enviar e-mail via php porem a função `mail()` não esta retornando nem um erro, e não sei se meu codigo esta errado:

```
<?php

$to = "MEU EMAIL";
$subject = "Php Mail";
$body = "Test Message From PHP";

$headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: Your name <info@address.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

Não retorna nem um erro, mais também não chega email, eu utilizo o hotmail.

Comment: Não foi para caixa de spam?

Comment: Não já verifiquei.

Comment: É muito comum a função mail não executar corretamente devido algum problema com a configuração de servidor. SMTP não é uma opção para ti?

Comment: Primeira vez trabalhando com Email não sei por onde começar então achei essa função, poderia mandar uma exemplo?

Comment: Eu coloquei meu email em `$to` publiquei no meu servidor e funcionou direitinho.